# Push new field and value to json array object in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm new to node.js. I need to display Name in jqgrid, but I stored only id of one document into another document.

**Example**

I have 2 documents like Student master and student mark document. I have to display mark details in jqgrid. In mark document I stored student id instead of name. How do I fetch the name and send a new object to jqgrid?

My code is as follows:

```
exports.getAllstudentsmark = function(req, callback)
{
    studentsmarks.find(function(error, studentsmarks_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {

        studentsmarks_collection.toArray(function(error, results) {
          if( error ) callback(error)
          else {
            newresult = results;
            for(i=0;i<results.length;i++)
            {
                newresult[i]['studentname'] = getStudentName(results[i].studentid);
            }
            console.log(newresult);
            callback(null, newresult)}
        });
      }
    });
}

var getstudentObjectId = function(id)
{
    return student.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id);
}
var getStudentName = function(id)
{
    student.findOne({_id: getstudentObjectId (id)}, function(e, o){
console.log(o.name);
        return o.name;
    });
}
```

newresult[i]['studentname'] is always getting undefined. But if I log into getStudentName function I can get answer into getStudentName function.

My callback function is only getting this problem. How to resolve and get my result in an easy way. Please help any one.

Answer (score 2):

try this inside your `for` loop

```
newresult.push({'studentname': getStudentName(results[i].studentid) });
```

exlpanation:
by the time you access `newresult[i]` it doesn't exist, so accessing `studentname` field of it is impossible

Comment: It's getting error like ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are not setting the name of the user into the array, but the return value of `student.findOne`, since this is an asynchronous method. Maybe try this thing

```
exports.getAllstudentsmark = function(req, callback)
{
  studentsmarks.find(function(error, studentsmarks_collection) {
  if( error ) callback(error)
  else {

    studentsmarks_collection.toArray(function(error, results) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        newresult = [];
        for(i=0;i<results.length;i++)
        {
            getStudentName(results[i].studentid, function (studentName) {
               newresult.push({studentname: studentName});
            })
        }
        console.log(newresult);
        callback(null, newresult)}
    });
  }
});
}

var getstudentObjectId = function(id)
{
    return student.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id);
}
var getStudentName = function(id, callback)

{
    student.findOne({_id: getstudentObjectId (id)}, function(e, o){
console.log(o.name);
        callback(o.name);
    });
}
```

I hope it helps